# Accessing a variable that starts with an integer within results generated by json_decode

Tags: php, json

I feel really stupid right now.  The following code *should* output 'If you can get this text to print, you're neat!', but it doesn't.  Any ideas?

```
<?php
$a = (Array) json_decode("{\"406\":\"If you can get this text to print, you're neat!\"}");
// dump($a);
echo $a[406]."\n";
echo $a["406"]."\n";
echo $a['"406"']."\n";
echo $a["'406'"]."\n";


$a = Array(406=>'Sanity check: this works, why don\'t any of the previous accessors work?');
// dump($a);
echo $a[406]."\n";


function dump($a) {
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        echo "$k=>$v\n";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Do `var_dump($a)` after you do the json_decode. It'll tell you exactly what the key is, and what its datatype is as well. I'm guessing it'll be blank and/or mangled, due to the (Array) casting.

Comment: Tried that already, but maybe I missed something:array(1) {
  ["406"]=>
  string(47) "If you can get this text to print, you're neat!"
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original example was returning an object because of a second optional parameter for return type that has the default of `FALSE`, or to return an object. This is how you would treat it...

```
$a = json_decode("{\"406\":\"If you can get this text to print, you're neat!\"}", FALSE);
echo $a->{"406"}; // If you can get this text to print, you're neat!
```

A little tweaking and you can create an array instead...

```
$a = json_decode("{\"406\":\"If you can get this text to print, you're neat!\"}", TRUE);
echo $a["406"]; // If you can get this text to print, you're neat!
```

... and you can reference `$a` as an array like you were originally attempting. Notice what was happening when you were trying to type cast the original object. Here's a var_dump of the original array you created followed by the resulting array from using the optional `TRUE` parameter.

```
array(1) { ["406"]=>  string(47) "If you can get this text to print, you're neat!" }
array(1) { [406]=>  string(47) "If you can get this text to print, you're neat!" }
```

Do you see how it was adding the quotes to your array key when you were type casting it from an object? This is why you weren't able to return the correct value; because the array key had changed.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you very much! :)  I still am curious why my original code doesn't work.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You don't need to specify a returned array as you did in your example - what json_decode was returning was an object and should be referenced differently. When you change the second optional parameter to `TRUE`, json_decode returns an array. I've added some more code to my answer so you can see the difference.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  After you posted your answer, I checked out php.net's documentation of the function signature.  It makes sense why this works, and it's just as clean of a solution as before.  The thing that doesn't make sense is why my original code doesn't work ("(Array)" casts the object to an array, and it doesn't appear that the member names were being mangled in the conversion, so the original code should have worked...?)

Comment: See above revision for a clue as to why your original code wasn't working. For some reason though, I'm unable to access that element via `$a["\"406\""]` and I don't rightly know why.

Answer (score 1):

This did work for me:

```
$a = json_decode("{\"406\":\"If you can get this text to print, you're neat!\"}", true);
```

I added another parameter to json_deocde.

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you very much! :)  I still am curious why my original code doesn't work.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your using a json object, not an array.

json object:

```
{"keyname":"keyvalue"}
```

Json array:

```
["value1","value2"]
```

Since it is an object, you can access it as such.

```
$json=json_decode("{'keyname':'keyvalue'}";
$keyname=$json->keyname;
```